# Which mobile apps support swiping/importing private keys via QR code?

Tags: paper-wallet, qrcode, private-key-import

The bitcoin.org site that provides a list of wallet clients doesn't clearly show which allow for importing bitcoin via a QR paper wallet. Does anyone know a location to see which support such features, or know of ones that work on mobile phones that clearly support swiping?

Answer (score 1):

These wallets do:

- Bitcoin Wallet
- Mycelium